# Calendar Overlay Color Menu

Tags: sharepoint-online, overlay, calendar-view

I have a SPO calendar with multiple calendar overlays and used a separate CSS for the overlay colors.  However, the default overlay colors, in the Color field drop-down menu, do not match the colors in the CSS file.  Is there a way to change the menu options in the Calendar Overlay settings Color field?  A screenshot is below.  Many thanks!

PLove
[image: Calendar Overlay Color Field Menu]

Answer (score 0):

The  menu options in the Calendar Overlay settings section is based on the look of your site. When you go to site settings-> change the look to change your site look, the menu options will also be changed.

You don't have to change the menu options, you could choose a color then override it with customized css in the page.

The colors are controlled by the css classes ms-acal-color1 to ms-acal-color9.

You can override to the style as below, then add the style into a content editor web part in the calendar view.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-acal-color1{
   background-color:lime !important;
}
</style>
```